# If statement for numbers in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create an SQL query to set a number in a column if another number is present.

```
UPDATE vrp_user_moneys 
SET
when bank = 0 then SET bank = 500000 ELSE bank end
```

I've had a look around but to no avail. How would I correct this query?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE vrp_user_moneys as v
SET v.bank = 500000
WHERE v.bank = 0;
```

Comment: When I started to reply, there was no reply, and when I sent it, there was a similar reply.
But I did not see it

Comment: could i help and sorry for the spelling and for teh reduntant answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```sql
UPDATE vrp_user_moneys
SET bank = 500000
WHERE bank = 0;
```